# Get type using reflection to feed to generic class

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I get the class name/type using the class name string? like

```
Dictionary<string, string> DFields = GetFields();
```

the type is

```
Dictionary<string, string>
object = Deserialize<?>(_stream)
```

Ideally, I was thinking:

```
object = Deserialize<"Dictionary<string, string>">(_stream)
```

It should become

```
object = Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(_stream)
```

in order to work. Im serializing like 10 object but I only have the type names in string format. I need to format the string format to actual type so I can feed it to the generic serializer deserializer function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1 - Get type instance:**

You need to use an assembly qualified name passed into `Type.GetType()`.
Doing a quick test by calling `GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` on a Dictionary() type instance, it turns out to be:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

quite a mess. I believe you can remove most of it though and it'll still work:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib

therefor:

```
var typeName = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib";
var type = Type.GetType( typeName );
```

**Step 2 (assuming the API forces a generic parameter which IMO is shit) - Use reflection to parametize the generic method dynamically:**

```
var genericMethod = typeof(Serialzier).GetMethod( "Deserializer" );
var parametizedMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod( type );
var parameters = new object[] { _stream };
var deserializedInstance = parametizedMethod.Invoke( null, parameters );
```

Comment: No. I only have Dictionary<string, string> as a string like "Dictionary<string, string>." I need to convert this string to an actual type like Dictionary<string, string>. It should become string type to actual real type.

Comment: When I try to do object.Deserialize<Type.GetType("Dictionary<string, string>")>(); it says: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'

Comment: This Protobuff-net deserializer only has method: Deserializer<T>(). No other deserialize method. I have to feed this string type to T.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Protobuff-net, but havning a quick look at that Serializer class, all it does internally is: `return (T) RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(source, null, typeof(T));`. Assuming `RuntimeTypeModel` is public, hopefully something like this works: `object = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(_stream, null, type);`.

Comment: Ok it works. Thanks a lot. I will keep this technique in mind when I see generics.

Comment: +1 For a very comprehensive answer. I'm surprised there aren't more upvotes